# Why does my matrix rotation not pass my school's unit test?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, matrix

Basically we were asked to create a matrix calls in C++ for my university course.

To start off, my class uses a column major constructor, but it places it in memory row major:

```
Matrix2::Matrix2(float R1C1, float R1C2, float R2C1, float R2C2)
{
    //Row major order.
    //Parameters written as column major (a normal matrix) but entered into memory as row major.
    matrix[0] = R1C1;
    matrix[1] = R2C1;
    matrix[2] = R1C2;
    matrix[3] = R2C2;
}
```

Which I believe is required for the unit test.
Matrices are defined as their identity matrix if no parameters are specified.

So, i rotate my matrix with this code:

```
void Matrix2::setRotateZ(float radians)
{
    (*this) = (*this)*Matrix2(  cosf(radians), -sinf(radians),
                                sinf(radians), cosf(radians));
}
```

I found this code on wikipedia and on my uni lecture slides. And it seems to go with column major matricies (which is how the data is meant to be input due to my constructor)

Also note that "setRotateZ" should actually be "rotateZ", as it accumulates rotation when called more than once.

My multiplication overload goes like this:

```
Matrix2 Matrix2::operator*(Matrix2& o)
{
    Matrix2 newMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    newMatrix.matrix[0] = matrix[0] * o.matrix[0] + matrix[2] * o.matrix[1];
    newMatrix.matrix[2] = matrix[0] * o.matrix[2] + matrix[2] * o.matrix[3];
    newMatrix.matrix[1] = matrix[1] * o.matrix[0] + matrix[3] * o.matrix[1];
    newMatrix.matrix[3] = matrix[1] * o.matrix[2] + matrix[3] * o.matrix[3];

    return newMatrix;
}
```

Which just multiplies like a normal matrix (given that it's row major, 0 is R1C1 and 1 is R2C1 etc)

So pretty much, if I swap:

```
-sinf(radians)
```

and

```
sinf(radians)
```

in my setRotateZ function above, all works well, the matrix passes all tests including multiplication, rotation and addition.

However, as it is shown now, the matrix fails rotation.

As far as I know, swapping the sign functions should work for row major matrices only, but because mine swaps it in the constructor, entering it as a column major should work.

What am I doing wrong? This is bugging me, even though I've gotten it to work by swapping the values, I want to know what's going on.

I'm pretty much a matrix newb, so a little help will be appreciated!

NOTE: The unit test works by comparing the results of an operation with what they should evaluate to.

Comment: Time to learn how to use your debugger that comes with your compiler toolset.

Comment: So it is a bug and not a misconception of how matrices work?

Comment: So I take it you've never used a debugger?  A debugger allows you to single-step through your program to determine where it goes against your planned approach.

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried debugging it before, and I'll keep trying.
I mainly just don't know what I'm looking for, as i don't fully understand how matrices work, which is why I thought it may be a conceptual problem and not a code problem. I suppose i shouldn't have posted the question here in that case.

My class seems to work how I predicted, but I'll keep looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To start off, my class uses a column major constructor, but it places
>   it in memory row major

Well, the code you posted shows the exact opposite ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order)):

```
Matrix2(float R1C1, float R1C2, float R2C1, float R2C2)
// this ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ is ROW major!
{
    matrix[0] = R1C1;
    matrix[1] = R2C1;  // <-- this is COLUMN major!
    matrix[2] = R1C2;  // <--
    matrix[3] = R2C2;
}
```

Besides, in order to apply a rotation (the math is correct) you have to multiply the rotation matrix by the other matrix while you are doing the opposite.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had doubts about the order of multiplication that I was doing.
This means that the reason it was working before, was because too many things were improper, causing the result to be proper...

Comment: Looking over the code in the unit test made by my uni, I realised that, they don't compare the results with pre-calculated values, but instead, they also create a new matrix with the pre-calculated values in it, using my matrix constructor, which means, switching between majors to make it easier to read when inputting, actually breaks the unit test...

So this was the main problem.

Comment: @killerloader you're welcome. I'm glad you solved the problem.

Comment: I just realised.
Multiplying (transformation)*(this) does the transformation globally, and (this)*(transformation) does it locally, relative to the rotation of the matrix.
Is this correct, or do I still have something backwards?

Comment: @killerloader I don't understand what you mean with _"(this)*(transformation) does it locally, relative to the rotation of the matrix."_. If you are talking about center of rotation, I'm afraid you are wrong... If you are considering the locality (scope) of the variables, it's the same.

Comment: Sorry, I'm speaking in relation to an opengl project. I should have said this earlier.
If I do: matrix = transformation * matrix, then the object connected to the matrix gets rotated around (0,0), which seems correct, and is the way you said is correct, but if i do matrix *= transformation, then the object gets rotated around its origin, which is more useful in a game situation.

Comment: @killerloader That's a question for OpenGl (yes, the column major was a big clue) experts (I'm not), but for what (the little) I can recall, usually all the transformations (rotation, translation, scale...) are "precomputed" by multiplying the relative matrices in the right order (there's a stack of them...) and then applied to the current vector. To rotate by a certain angle from a certain center you should translate to the origin, rotate and then translate back.